# selector for absence of class in element or its parents

Tags: css, mediawiki

I am trying to alter MediaWiki's hideous default color for visited links and keep the red color for new links. New links have class *new* or their parents have this class set. So I tried

```
:not(.new) a:not(.new) { color: #0074D9 !important; }
```

But as I inspected in the browser console, this rule overwrites `li.new a` - which it should not. Experimenting a bit,

- `li:not(.new) a:not(.new)` keeps the red color for `li.new a`,
- `*:not(.new) a:not(.new)` overwrites the red color

Can you explain this behavior and recommend a CSS rule forcing blue color for all links but the new ones?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You might be interested in the [ongoing discussion](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T213778) about changing that color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:not(.new)` will match *every element* that does not have a `new` class. So for example `:not(.new) a` in `<li class="new"><span><a>...</a></span></li>` will match `span a`. In general, `:not()` is rather hazardous to use without an accompanying specific class or id that you know won't be used elsewhere.

What you want is "`a` tags which do not have a `.new` ancestor" (as opposed to "`a` tags which have a non-`.new` ancestor"), which cannot be expressed as a CSS selector. Given you know that the `.new` element is the grandparent, you might be able to write something like `:not(.new) > * > a` instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the `<span>` role and for the discussion link. I ended up with `a { color: #0074D9 !important; }
a.new, .new a { color: #ba0000 !important; }` as a *nuclear option* for time being, MediaWiki has some issues to solve today.

Answer (score 1):

set a color for  `li.new a` and `li a.new` and then set a color for `li:not(.new) a` and `li a:not(.new)` .

If you want just the visited links to change color add `:visited` to the css selectors

```css
ul li.new a, ul li a.new {
color:red
}
li:not(.new) a {
color:green
}
a:not(.new) {
color:green
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <a href="#" >Normal Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class='new'>
     <a href="#">this will NOT be  green because LI has class new </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#" class='new'>this will NOT be green because it has class new</a>
  </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" >Normal Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```